# How to remove "g" with regex from this list in python with regex?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have this list:

```
list = ['12kg','900g', '2,7kg', '801g', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
```

and I want to remove only letter `g` (or replace with `""`) when I have pattern `<number>g`, which means:

```
new_list = ['12kg', '900', '2,7kg', '801', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg]
```

I've tried to write the following but failed they all failed:

- `[^kK]g`: for some reason gets last digit (`0g` and `1g`)
- `[^kK]g$`: nothing comes up (I expected the sign `$` would get the end of string)
- `[^kK](g)`: it does work but in a group -> How do I replace the group match with what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `list` is a built-in type in Python, so you can use for example `lst` instead or else it will be shadowed.

Using `[^kK]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 1 character other than `k` or `K` which is a broader match than a digit.

What you could do is match a `g` char followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match like `4gram`, and assert a digit to the left.

Then in the replacement use an empty string.

```
(?<=\d)g\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CoYB8B/1)

```
lst = ['12kg','900g', '2,7kg', '801g', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
new_lst = [re.sub(r'(?<=\d)g\b', r'', s) for s in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Output

```
['12kg', '900', '2,7kg', '801', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import re


lst = ['12kg', '900g', '2,7kg', '801g', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
newLst = [re.sub('([0-9]+)g$', lambda x: x.groups()[0], el) for el in lst]
print(newLst)  # => ['12kg', '900', '2,7kg', '801', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
```

The regex I used here was `([0-9]+)g$`. This will match the string with at least one number and end with "g". The `re.sub` call will then replace the string with only the number part.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import re
list = ['12kg','900g', '2,7kg', '801g', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
[re.sub('(\d)g', r'\1',x) for x in list]

['12kg', '900', '2,7kg', '801', '15', '3,63kg', '1kg']
```

This matches a digit followed by g, and substitutes back the digit alone. The trick is `\d` matches a digit, `(\d)` puts the matched digit into a group, and `\1` substitute group 1, which is the digit without the g.